# Redirect when click on submit button not allowed blocked for some reason.(JSF 2.0)

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, captcha

I have a very strange issue with one of my forms.

I have a form that registers a user and sends him/her an email. Wanted to replace my old captcha with the new primefaces one. Everything was going fine, but when i click on the submit button(and the captcha is correctly entered), the data is saved in the database, the email is sent, but i dont get redirected to the destination page. Ill show you just a bit of code so you know what i am talking about:

This is the component i just added inside my form

```
<p:captcha label="Captcha" language="en" theme="white" publicKey="6Ld7pMESAAAAAHd1VihJkqPUXAJVwU3Cghc8fzrq"/> 
            <h:commandButton value="Registruj"
                    actionListener="#{registrationControllerBuyer.doRegisterBuyer}"/>
```

also i added a couple of configurations at the web.xml:

```
<!-- keys gotten from recaptcha -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.PUBLIC_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name>
    <param-value>6Ld7pMESAAAAAHd1VihJkqPUXAJVwU3Cghc8fzrq</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.PRIVATE_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name>
    <param-value>6Ld7pMESAAAAAMhr5WSk5bcRrff8Y08NtDi8Buoq</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And this is the bit of java for the button handler:

```
public String doRegisterBuyer() throws Exception {
    Buyer buyer = new Buyer();
    buyer.setName(getName());
    buyer.setSecondName(getSecondName());
    buyer.setNickName("not specified");
    buyer.setEmail(getEmail());
    buyer.setPassword(getPassword());
    buyer.setAcceptedTermsAndConditions(isAcceptedTermsAndConditions());
    buyer.setNewsletterSubscription(isNewsletterSubscription());
    buyer.setAccountStatus(AccountStattus.CREATED.toString());      

    Buyer tmpBuyer = tmpBuyer = buyersRegistratorEJB.createBuyer(buyer);

    // Send activation link to user
    emailServiceEJB.sendAccountActivationLinkToBuyer(tmpBuyer.getEmail()
            .trim(), tmpBuyer.getName());
    return "registrationSucceded.xhtml";
}
```

The captcha seems to work perfectly:
-If i give wrong input to the captcha the method doRegisteredBuyer() don't gets executed
-If i get right input to the captcha the method doRegisteredBuyer() does get executed **BUT** i dont get redirected to registrationSucceded.xhtml

Why is that(the name of the page is correct, already checked that a few times :) )?

Comment: Please note that I edited my answer because I totally misread the code snippet. I saw a `<p:commandButton>` where you actually posted `<h:commandButton>`. It's Friday...

Comment: :) i did read it. It is ok now. It works now. i get an error but this is not related to the captcha hehe..: 

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 5.4.5 Daily sending quota exceeded. z18sm1730598bkf.20 You are right it is Friday, i think i finish my working for today. Thanks have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `action`, not `actionListener`.

```
<h:commandButton value="Registruj" action="#{registrationControllerBuyer.doRegisterBuyer}"/>
```

#### See also:

- [Difference between `action` and `actionListener`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/3909382#3909382)